# JavaScript, how to create difference of date with moment.js

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with creating an error message on a page where there is a "from date:", and a "to date:". If the difference between the two dates is greater than or equal to 60 days, I have to put up an error message.

I am trying to use moment.js and this is what my code is looking like now. It was recommended that I use it in knockout validation code. this is what it looks like right now:

```
var greaterThan60 = (moment().subtract('days', 60) === true) ? "The max range for from/to date is 60 days." : null;
```

I am still not sure how to make it greater than 60 days, not just equal to 60 days. This is what my boss gave me to help.

**[Reference site for `moment().subtract`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)**

Comment: use this mithod moment(fromDate, 'dateformat').diff(moment(toDate,'dateFormat'),'days')

Answer (score 0):

moment.js provides a diff() method to find difference between dates. please check below example.

```
var fromDate = 20180606;
    var toDate = 20180406;

    var dif = moment(fromDate, 'YYYYMMDD').diff(moment(toDate, 'YYYYMMDD'),'days')
    console.log(dif) // 61
```

Answer (score 0):

`subtract` returns a new moment object. So checking for true always returns false. You can use `range` and `diff` to calculate a diff in days and check that:

```
let start = moment('2016-02-27');
let end = moment('2016-03-02');

let range = moment.range(start, end);

let days = range.diff('days');

let error = null;
if (days > 60) {
    error = "The max range for from/to date is 60 days.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this.

```
var date = Date.parse("2018-04-04 00:00:00");
var selectedFromDate = new Date(date);
var todayDate = new Date();
var timedifference = Math.abs(todayDate.getTime() - selectedFromDate.getTime());
var daysDifference = Math.ceil(timedifference/(1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

just use if else loop for greater than 60 days validation.

```
if(daysDifference > 60)
{
    alert("From Date should be less than 2 months");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.isSameOrAfter` function to compare if the end value is greater than or equal to the start value plus sixty days. Example:

```
var greaterThan60 = toDate.isSameOrAfter(startDate.add(60, 'days'));
```

where `toDate` is your end time as a moment object and `startDate` is the start time as a moment object. If the end date is greater than or equal to 60 days after the start date, `greaterThan60` will be true.

References:

[isSameOrAfter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/)

[add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)